# add(1)(2)(3).total === 6 - Has anyone else seen self returning functions used like this?

Tags: javascript

The following code works, and while I understand why it works, I haven't seen it anywhere. I assume this is because all the other design patterns are much better.

I would still have expected to see the example as a cautionary tale along the line but I have not.

Sure, it is awful, especially with the example below which I chose because it is clear what it does but:

What is this pattern called?

Is it commonly used?

Are there any legitimate projects that use this pattern?

```
var add = function container (val) {

  addFunc = function f (val, undefined) {
  addFunc.total += val;
  return addFunc;
  };

addFunc.total = 0;

return addFunc(val);
};

alert(add(1)(2)(3).total);
alert(add(1)(2)(33).total);
```

Edit: Variable name change so that the code works in IE.

Comment: This design pattern rather looks like a puzzle than a clean code :)

Comment: But WHY would you do something like that?!

Comment: This pattern doesn't seem terrible to me. It's very clear to read. I guess I'd rather see the `total` as a local variable, and the `.total` property as a method that returns the result, and resets the variable.

Comment: @AleksG - You probably shouldn't, I did something else by accident and had to modify it to get a working example. I don't have a reason why - I would have posted this earlier but I was worried people would use it.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky - I'm sure it is a good thing I've never seen this in the wild.

Comment: @user989370: Why is that? What specifically is objectionable about it to you? I don't know how the code could be any more clear.

Comment: @amnotiam  - I'm glad, clear is what I was aiming for when I wrote the example. It is not something I have seen, it came about as the result of a typo I made and I wrote the example because it is easy enough to follow.<br />

I think my main objection is: When would I use this?
<br />
As to readability, we have:
<br />
add(1)(2)(3) vs add(1).add(2).add(3) vs add(1,2,3).

While add(1,2,3) wins on brevity, I like add(1)(2)(3) because in more complex examples it is clear that it is 3 separate operations that complete in order and not one function that uses 3 parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, this could be considered chaining or encapsulation.

You chain when you can perform a set of operations indefinitely off an original function. jQuery uses a form of this when you can chain calls to set properties and attributes off an original selector. In this situation, the creator wanted to be able to chain calls to add without having to retype the function name. Not the cleanest of ideas, but valid.

Also, since the actual body of the code is never exposed to the caller, this could also be considered encapsulation since the `addFunc` method is not exposed to the outside scope.

Comment: I'm the creator - I didn't really create it with a purpose, it is the result of a typo I cleaned up into a working example, but the rest of what you said it perfect.

I didn't expect to have done it first so to speak, I was hoping it had a name, something with pop, like "self-invoking anonymous function" - there is a name you won't forget.

Comment: I forgot: I have seen method chaining before (and am fond of it in jQuery) and I understand why it works, I was mostly trying to understand why this way and not another.

Answer (score 4):

This is a functional programming concept called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Essentially, given a `function foo(a, b, c)` you create a `function bar(a)` that returns `function bar2(b)` that returns `function bar3(c)` that gives the final answer.

Technically, this isn't true currying because it goes on infinitely and uses a side-effect (the `total` property) to break out of the infinite loop.

But in any case, there can be useful applications of this pattern. It's particularly useful for traversing tree structures where you're calculating some result for each leaf of the tree where the result depends on the ancestry of that leaf. You run the curried function on the root node, and then run the returned function on each child node, and then for each of those child nodes, etc. A pure curried function would return another function if the node it's running on has children, and would return the desired value if you've reached a leaf.

The code would be a simple recursive function that passes to itself a new "root" node and the function to parse it with, that always takes one argument.

But, the way it's being used here looks more like a learning exercise rather than something useful.

EDIT: If you wanted to make it a pure currying function but still have the quasi-infinite recursion, the input data needs to provide the stop information (just like a C-string uses the value `0x00` to define `EOF`):

```
var add = (function() {
    var total = 0;
    return function nextAdd(a) {
        if(a != null) {
            total += a;
            return nextAdd;
        } else {
            return total;
        }
    };
})();
```

Then, `add(1)(2)(3)(null) === 6` and there's no `.total` side-effect parameter.

Comment: As the entire code can be replaced with 1+2+3 - it definitely wasn't meant to be used like this, this is only to show it actually runs.

Comment: Hey, just added a pure currying version of the adder for you to check out.

Comment: Thanks for the example - the .total part was bolted on to my example at the end to show it worked, it was not really planned out - I was mostly going for speed with some readability. I think I'll look further into currying as that seems to be where the leap from here to code with a real world use.

Comment: Now that I think about it, what you're doing is also related to the concept of [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

You would be infinitely better off with:

```
function add() {
    var l = arguments.length, i, sum = 0;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) sum += arguments[i];
    return sum;
}
alert(add(1,2,3)); // 6
```

Really, there should be no reason for the code style you're asking about. I have not seen any legitimiate use, only arbitrary `arguments` length.

Comment: I think the most obvious improvement is - 1+2+3. Obviously the example I used it for is illustration only and not something anyone would ever do (I hope!). I don't really have a use for it, and haven't ever used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Currying [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). From the name of Haskell Curry [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry) ( but originally developped by Moses Ilyich Schönfinkel [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sch%C3%B6nfinkel) ).

> A technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments (or an n-tuple of arguments) in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions each with a single argument(partial application).

From [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) form 2010:

> When to Use Currying - When you find yourself calling the same function and passing mostly the same parameters,then the function is probably a good candidate for currying. You can create a new function dynamically by partially applying a set of arguments to your function. The new function will keep the repeated parameters stored (so you don’t have to pass them every time) and will use them to pre-fill the full list of arguments that the original function expects.

Another [article for currying](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/) from Dustin Diaz.